# How do I reference an object inline in LyX that is in a knitr chunk?

Tags: lyx, knitr

Suppose I have an object that was processed in an earlier knitr chunk, say

```
my_df <- read.dta('somefile.dta')
x <- mean(my_df$age)
```

Putting an inline knitr chunk does not work -- the knitr chunk is written out as text; it is not processed. And I don't think I can use `\Sexpr{x}` because I don't seem to be able to refer to `x` in `\Sexpr{}`.

I'm using LyX 2.0.3 and svn, and knitr version .3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can use `x` in `\Sexpr{}` after the chunk in which `x` was created. Did you *really* try it at all? One reminder, though, is that you have to use TeX code in LyX to input `\Sexpr{x}` (press `Ctrl+L`) to make sure `\` is not translated to `\backslash`.

Comment: This did not work for me. After upgrading to .3.5 it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... that sounds weird; I did not change anything about `\Sexpr{}` recently.